# Embedding PNG files that are retrieved by sending post data to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, image, post

I've searched for this answer in the past but have never come across an answer for this problem. I'm hoping the SO community can finally put this question to rest. **I need to know how to embed an image whose source bytes are retrieved via a POST request in JavaScript/ JQuery.** POST is needed because in order to generate the image the server needs to be sent a base64 encoded string of instructions from the client. Sometimes those instructions are too lengthy to be sent via GET. Also, I'm working with some legacy code right now, so I'm trying to avoid changing major functions of the server code. It's still sth that is possible to do, just not preferred as editing server code won't always be an option in future situations.

I know you can embed base64 in an img tag. I know you can also do it by rendering the data on a canvas. But both of those methods require you either have an **encoded base64 string**...

`<img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0.....AwXEQA7'>`

**A standard URL...**

`<img src="www.examplesite.com/theimage.png">`

**Or a URL that uses GET parameters.**

`<img src="www.examplesite.com/getImage.php?id=9001">`

**What about a URL that uses POST parameters?**

```
<script>
var url = 'www.examplesite.com/getImage.php';
var postData = {'id': 9001};
var outDiv = document.getElementById("outputDiv");
$.post(url,postData,function(data){

    // What do we do here to display the returned image?
    // The image will have the Content-Type: 'image/png'.

});
</script>
```

Comment: The simplest way is to POST to getImageurl.php?id=9001 and get url to the generated image stored in short living temp storage (1-5 min). Then set that url to img src.

Comment: Ahaaa. Let me try both of these lovely methods. Thanks! I'll get back after trying these out. 

Alright- btoa throws an error that the data contains non latin characters... (data is already encoded to be a PNG file. If following a GET url like this in a browser you would be able to view the image in a new tab with no HTML on the page).

The other idea sounds very promising. Thanks guys! I think I've got it!

Comment: Not "both methods" but one; it's the same. @dewd explained it in more detailed manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the post data, create the image on the server, then return a code to the client to access the image e.g. imagabd1. Then have a getImage.php script which returns an image via a get with a unique identifier to the image created. Add an image element to the DOM and add the get request as the src. Example:

1) Post sends base64 data.

2) Server creates image and stores on server

3) Server returns a code, e.g. imagabd1

4) Create an image element on the client and add http://server/getImage?id=imagabd1 as the source. The server should know what image to return given this get request.

Comment: And then delete the image off the server  as soon as the URL has been accessed, or if time since creation is more than X minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is returning the Base64, should be as simple as:

```
outDiv.html('<img src="' + data '">');
```

Or change the SRC attr of an image:

```
element.attr('src', data)
```

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the server was returning in base64 format. It's returning the data as a straight up image file though. Image headers make it so the browser will display the content directly. Example at this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012459/a-php-page-in-img-src

+1 to your answer as it may help someone else in the future though.